# Is there anyway to know if users bring up app by clicking in notification center?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

in method 
`didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` i need to detect if it is invoked because user click on a notification in Notification Center or not to have appropriate actions.

Is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

using **didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification** you cannot check if app is opened from local notification push notification or by directly clicking on the app icon.

But,

what you can do is in method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

write this code

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]!=nil) {
// App opened from push notification but app was not in background
}else if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]!=nil){
    // App opened from local notification and app was in background
}
```

and in method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

you can detect if app is opened from local notification when app was in background

and finally one last method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

In this method you can check if app is opened from push notification when app was either running or it was in backround

I guess this will help u in knowing if app is opened from notification centre or from somewhere else